# Jquery image slider without restriction of width

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

I have used the coin slider in my application.But the coin slider is restricted by the width.In my application ,I have split the document into two columns.The first column only contains coin slider.The second column contains the login panel.According to the width of the second column,the first column was adjust.I need to run my application in various screen size like `1280*768`,`800*600`.is there any image slider in jquery without restrict width of image?Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    id = '#coin-slider1'.replace(/:/g, "\\:");
                    var sliderWidth="";
                    jQuery(id).coinslider({width:sliderWidth,height:screen.height/4,delay:500});
                })
```

Comment: so without seeing any html/css I'm guessing your column is of variable width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measure the width of the first column before using that value in the options array that you pass into the plugin...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    id = '#coin-slider1'.replace(/:/g, "\\:");
    var sliderWidth = $('#column1').width();
    jQuery(id).coinslider({width:sliderWidth,height:screen.height/4,delay:500});
})
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply.Then My coin slider is within the tabpanel.So i set the width of the tabPanel.But that not working.I set like this, var sliderWidth = $('#tabPanel').width();.What i do wrong?Please help me.

Comment: do you get a value for $('#tabPanel').width(); use console.log or alert()

Answer (score 0):

I have fix my problem with the help of calumbrodie.Thanks to calumbrodie.
I set the width of the tabPanel(parne to fo div of slider) as width of slider.
i got the width by the below code

```
document.getElementById('homeContentSubView:homeForm:tabPanel').offsetWidth
```

And my full code is,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    id = '#coin-slider1'.replace(/:/g, "\\:");     
                    var sliderWidth = "";                                         sliderWidth=document.getElementById('homeContentSubView:homeForm:tabPanel').offsetWidth-30;                                                       jQuery(id).coinslider({width:sliderWidth,height:screen.height/4,delay:750});
                })
```

Thanks to all.