# JQuery Slider width, variable <li> element widths - how do?

Tags: jquery, slider, width

*Disclaimer - have read several [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860366/jquery-image-slider-without-restriction-of-width) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489737/jquery-slider-with-variable-width-elements) but they don't seem to have addressed my exact issue.*

#### The problem

My slider panel contains an unordered list, with varying numbers of `<li>` elements of varying widths. Each LI contains an image, hence the reason for the different sizes. *e.g. 5 elements = 2000px, 6 elements = 2100px*

Now. If I set the slider to have a fixed width of `2500px`, the `li` elements display correctly in the slider.

However, because the `li` total width varies, there is a varying amount of blank space to scroll at the end of the slider which ruins the effect.

If I **do not** specify the width of the UL in the CSS, my LI elements will float normally and `wrap`, rather than filling the width of the slider (because there is no explicit width).

#### What I tried

So I came up with the idea of:

```
$('ul#slide-ul li').each(function(){ 
        sliderWidth += $(this).outerWidth(); // LI's have padding
});
```

which returns the correct, actual width of the content of the slider. I can use this value to set the width of the slider, and everything works fine - offline.

Online, in FF, Chrome and IE, the first time the page loads, the LI's display as if there was no width set. I then **refresh** the page, and everything is ok.

I think this happens because the images inside the LI's haven't been cached or loaded at this point, and there is no pre-determined width so the LI's aren't their `true` size.

#### Summary

Is there a better way of getting the width of an UL that has varying content, for use within a slider, and preventing this issue with the page loading/refresh.

Sorry for the lengthy, hard to follow post, but am unable to post a live link. I will do a js fiddle if it will help, but there's a lot of code unfortunately.

Thank you.

### Edit

http://jsfiddle.net/VV7qp/6/

Here's a JSFiddle more or less. It's quite hard to replicate I'm afraid without a live server.

Comment: I'll do a PasteBin or something, 1 minute.

Comment: In your actual code, is the size of the image part of the markup?

Comment: Have you tried a plug and play jQuery Slider? Try Lemmon Slider - its made for variable widths!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSFiddle the width is already defined on all the img elements, can't you put the width on the li elements as well?

If you want that dynamically, maybe you could do something like:
give the images a class called 'imgClass'

```
$('ul#slide-ul li').each(function(){
    $(this).width($('.imgClass', this).width());
```

Comment: My JSFiddle was rushed, the image elements don't have the actual dimensions but this could be something I could look in to (would require some refactoring elsewhere). This looks like it could work as well so +1 thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look into `white-space: nowrap;`

Answer (score 1):

Building on the white-space answer because I think one solution is to force all your images to display on one line (so you get the ul width) this you can do using `inline-blocks`

**[here's a forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/K7qKT/)**

I haven't touched the JS, but it **will** need changed as you will no longer need to calculate the width of the `slide-ul` you can use the width of the `.carousel-container` and `#slide-ul` width I was too lazy to go in and amend all the calculations to rebuild the scroller

using `display: inline-block` and telling the `whitespace between them not to wrap`, will force `#slide-ul` to always be wide enough to contain all the images and because

`<div style="overflow: hidden;" class="scroll-pane ui-widget  ui-corner-all">`

has it's `overflow` set to `hidden` it's the one that is cropping the `ul` (which is now not a ul ;)), and it, as far as I can see, is the same width as `.carousel-container` so you have the figures you need?

I think that getting the images all on one line is the issue here?

Comment: Haven't got it working yet but this is the most promising answer so far and I can see the logic behind it. I will see if I get any more input and then accept. It's not the easiest question to understand fully without the actual source so thank you for your efforts.